# Laravel date input format validation

Tags: laravel, validation, date

Is it possible to validate date input to name of day followed by a comma, then the day of the month, then the month and finally the year in full? eg Sunday, 31 December 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`date_format`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-date-format) validation rule with a custom defined [date format string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
'some_date' => 'date_format:"l, j F Y"',
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Wasn't working at first, but realised that double quotes have to be used to specify the format. If others are wondering, to get the date into a format for the database, use `strtotime` and `Carbon::createFromTimestamp`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to make your own custom validation function :)

More details you can find here:
[custom validator](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily download Carbon package from `packagist.org`

and then use every format you want.

For example :

```
$dt = Carbon::create(1975, 12, 25, 14, 15, 16);

echo $dt->toDayDateTimeString();                   // Thu, Dec 25, 1975 2:15 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Core PHP like this:

```
$date = '2018-01-01';
echo date('l, j F Y', strtotime($date));
```